# WPF4 support for MVVM Light Toolkit

Tags: mvvm-light

When installing the package, I only get binaries for Silverlight 3/4/5 and Windows Phone, nothing for WPF. What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks guys, sorry if my question was not detailed enough.

I've been using the procedure described at Laurent's Website and in the binaries directory, I have only 5 dirs corresponding to Silverlight 3/4/5, WP7 and WP71. Nothing about .Net 4.

I've tried GalaSoft.MvvmLight.V3.0.2.19 and GalaSoft.MvvmLight.V4beta1.4.0.2.19 with the same result.

On the v4 beta 1, the install window doesn't show .Net in the binaries nor the Snippets.

Could this be related to the fact that I'm using Studio 2010 Express despite that Laurent said that his package can also be used with Express? I can understand that for the snippets, not for the binaries.

Comment: For the future I would recomment asking more specific questions as the commuity cannot know what you have done and how you reaced the point your at. So **please be more specific**.

Answer (score 0):

They're labelled as ".Net 4". Should be there along with Silverlight and Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not describe how you installed MVVM Light I cannot answer your question as to what went wrong. However, I can describe the easiest way of including MVVM Light into your project:

1. Install the NuGet package manager.
2. Create your project (WPF / SL / WP7).
3. Install one of the following packages

   - [MVVM Light](http://nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight)
     This installs version 3 of MVVM Light and also configures your project to the conventions used by MVVM Light.
   - [MVVM Light Libraries Only](http://nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibs)
     Installs only the version 3 libraries, but leaves your project untouched.
   - [MVVM Light [Preview]](http://nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightPreview)
     Installs version 4 of MVVM Light, including the project conventions.
   - [MVVM Light Libraries Only [Preview]](http://nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightPreview) 
     INstalls the version 4 libraries, but leaves your project unchanged.

Alternatively you can use the installer using the installer and the [procedure](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/installing/) described at Laurent's web site. If you use this approach the libraries should be installed under `%program files%\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Binaries` or the path you specified during the install.

The installer is good for installing the templates, snippets, etc., however, for production I strongly recommend using the NuGet packages as they usually offer an upgrade path should there be bugfixes.